# How to scrape a pivot table with Beautiful Soup

Tags: pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-table, wikipedia

I'm trying to scrape [a complex Wikipedia table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese-Language_Proficiency_Test#Applications_and_results) (I'm not sure if it's appropriate to generalize such tables with the term "pivot table") using Beautiful Soup in hopes of recreating a simpler, more-analyzable version of it in Pandas.

[JLPT "Applications and results" table on English Wikipedia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsHBP.png)

As an overview, moving from the left side: the table lists the years when JLPT was held, which exam levels were open that year, and then the statistics defined by the columns on top. The aggregated columns don't really matter for my purposes, although it'd be nice if there's a way to scrape and reconstruct them as such.

What makes the table difficult to reconstruct is that it has grouped rows (the years under column 'Year'), but the rows of that year are placed in the same hierarchical level as the year header, not under. Further, instead of having a `<th>` tag of the year in each `<tr>` row, it's only present in the first row of the year group:

[HTML structure of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33Lsu.png)

Another problem is that the year headers do not have any sort of defining identifiers in their tags or attributes, so I also can't pick only the rows with years in it.

These things make it impossible to group the rows by year.

So far, the only way I've been able to reconstruct *some* of the table is by:

1. scraping the entire table,
2. appending every `<tr>` element into a list,
3. since every year has a citation in square brackets: deleting every instance of strings with a `[` in it, resulting in a uniform length of elements in every row
4. converting them into a pandas dataframe (manually adding column names, removing leftover HTML using regex, etc.), without the years:

[Row elements in a list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pD3VQ.png)

[Processed dataframe (minus the years)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yG82Q.png)

After coming this far, now I realize that it's still difficult to group the rows by years without doing so manually. I'm wondering if there's a simpler, more straightforward way of scraping similarly complex tables with only BeautifulSoup itself, and little to no postprocessing in pandas. In this case, it's okay if it's not possible to get the table in its original pivot format, I just want to have the year value for each row. Something like:

[Dataframe goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaqOf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use BeautifulSoup to do this. Instead, you can use `pd.read_html` directly to get what you need. When you read the HTML from Wikipedia, it will pull in all of the tables into a list. If you scan through the list, you will see that it is the 10th dataframe.

```
df = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese-Language_Proficiency_Test')[10]
```

From there, you'll do some data cleaning to create the table that you need.

```
# Convert multi-level column into single columns
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)

#Fix column names
df = df.rename({'Year_Year': 'dummy_year',
                'Level_Level': 'level',
                'JLPT in Japan_Applicants': 'japan_applicants',
                'JLPT in Japan_Examinees': 'japan_examinees',
                'JLPT in Japan_Certified (%)': 'japan_certified',
                'JLPT overseas_Applicants': 'overseas_applicants',
                'JLPT overseas_Examinees': 'overseas_examinees',
                'JLPT overseas_Certified (%)': 'overseas_certified'},
               axis=1)

# Remove text in [], (). Remove commas. Convert to int.
df['japan_certified']    = df['japan_certified'].str.replace(r'\([^)]*\)', '', regex=True).str.replace(',', '').astype(int)
df['overseas_certified'] = df['overseas_certified'].str.replace(r'\([^)]*\)', '', regex=True).str.replace(',', '').astype(int)
df['dummy_year']         = df['dummy_year'].str.replace(r'\[.*?\]', '', regex=True)
```

Output:

```
    dummy_year  level  ...  overseas_examinees  overseas_certified
0         2007  1 kyū  ...              110937               28550
1         2007  2 kyū  ...              152198               40975
2         2007  3 kyū  ...              113526               53806
3         2007  4 kyū  ...               53476               27767
4         2008  1 kyū  ...              116271               38988
..         ...    ...  ...                 ...                 ...
127     2022-1     N1  ...               49223               17282
128     2022-1     N2  ...               54542               25677
129     2022-1     N3  ...               41264               21058
130     2022-1     N4  ...               40120               19389
131     2022-1     N5  ...               30203               16132
```